# Anonymous type and tuple

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, language-features, anonymous-types, tuples

What is the difference between anonymous type and tuple?

Comment: Here is an article explaining what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee957397.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Anonymous types have property names which carry more information, for tuples you don't have this.  You can't use anonymous types as return values and parameters though and you can with tuples.

An example of when a tuple is nice is when you want to return multiple values.  @Petar Minchev [mentions this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee957397.aspx) which gives a good example.

You may want a `Find()` method that returns both an index and the value.   Another example would be the position in a 2d or 3d plane.

Comment: this is a 11 year old answer, so im not sure if its relevant, but anonymous types can be used as a return value.

Answer (score 46):

Just a little update to this answer since C# 7 is out in the wild. Tuples have super powers now and can sometimes replace anonymous types and classes. Take for example this method that accepts and returns tuples with named properties.

To help illustrate what is possible, the `Whatever` function transforms the input shape and values.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var tupleInput = (Neat: 123, Cool: true);
    var tupleOutput = Whatever(tupleInput);
    Debug.Assert(tupleOutput.Something == 133);
    Debug.Assert(tupleOutput.Another == "True");
}

(int Something, string Another) Whatever((int Neat, bool Cool) data)
{
    return (Something: data.Neat + 10, Another: data.Cool.ToString());
}
```

That's cool.

Comment: Keep in mind that these tuples are not the same as good old Tuples or anonymous types. They are ValueTuples which are structures with fields, whereas anon types are classes with properties.

Answer (score 23):

A tuple is not an anonymous type, it's a named type.  You can use it as a return type or method argument.  This code is valid:

```
Tuple<int, string> GetTuple()
{
    return Tuple.Create(1, "Bob");
}
```

You can't do this with an anonymous type, you would have to return `System.Object` instead.  Typically, you end up having to use Reflection on these objects (or `dynamic` in .NET 4) in order to obtain the values of individual properties.

Also, as Brian mentions, the property names on a `Tuple` are fixed - they're always `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3` and so on, whereas with an anonymous type you get to choose the names.  If you write:

```
var x = new { ID = 1, Name = "Bob" }
```

Then the anonymous type actually has `ID` and `Name` properties.  But if you write:

```
Tuple.Create(1, "Bob")
```

Then the resulting tuple just has properties `Item1` and `Item2`.

Comment: The part about names "always `Item1`, `Item2`" is no longer correct with C# 7.  See @alex-dresko response above.

Comment: Item1 and Item2 still can be used even if its properties are named ID and Name.
item1 would then refernece ID. This works in C#7 and above.

Answer (score 8):

Another point in favor of anonymous types would be that you can easily have more than 8 properties. While this is doable using tuples, it's not so pretty.

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, Tuple.Create(8, 9)); //and so on
```

or write your own tuple classes.

---

An interesting similarity to note is that both tuples and anonymous types give you immutability and equality comparability (both overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode`) based on the properties by default.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget ValueTuple :)

Key Differences of the three:

| Name | Access modifier | Type | Custom member name | Deconstruction support | Expression tree support |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anonymous types | internal | class | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ |
| Tuple | public | class | ❌ | ❌ | ✔️ |
| ValueTuple | public | struct | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ |

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/choosing-between-anonymous-and-tuple